# Is Conway assuming that when the limit is $\infty$, it exists ?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, power-series

In the book of *Complex Analysis* by Conway, at page 31-32, it is given that

[image]

and in the next page, it is also given that

[image]

However, the author uses this proposition for the example:

[image]

But, $R$ can be infinite and zero, and in this particular case, the given limit in the proposition is

$$\lim n+1 = \infty :\quad \text{does not exists}.$$

So, how can we use the proposition 1.4 in this case ?

Is the author considering $\infty$ as a possible limit value - i.e is he assuming the limit exists when the limit is $\infty$ ?

As far as I understand, since the limit $\lim n+1 = \infty$, we cannot use the proposition 1.4.

So what am I missing in here ?

Comment: In the context of radius of convergence, $\infty$ is always a feasible value; this greatly simplifies arguments.

Comment: If you are sceptical of Conway's argument, then why not prove the result yourself from scratch?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Because I couldn't. Leave that a side, I couldn't understand the given proof either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guessed it right: for Conway, $\lim_{n\to\infty}n+1=\infty$.

Comment: What about the proposition itself ? is the equality $R = \lim |\frac{ a_n}{ a_{n+1}}| $ true even the limit is not finite ?

Comment: I'm asking this because I haven't figured out all of the proof, so I'm not sure when assuming $R = \infty$ would cause any trouble.

Comment: If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right\rvert=\infty$ then the radius of convergence is $\infty$, yes. That's what happens with the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$, for instance.